# how to write a customize hash function for unordered set which defined in the customize structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-set

I'm trying to write a new hash function for my own structure. Here is my code:

```
struct people{
    int id;
    unordered_set<people>friends;
    people(int x) : id(x) {}
};
```

And I need a hash function for the friends, like:

```
struct peopleHash{
    size_t operator()(const people& p) const{
        return p.id;
    }
}
```

And here comes the problem: if I initialize people first, the peopleHash function would find "undefined type people". The same thing happens if I initialize peopleHash first. I tried to define peopleHash inside of the people struct, like:

```
struct people{
    int id;
    struct peopleHash{
        size_t operator()(const people& p) const{
            return p.id;
        }
    };
    unordered_set<people, peopleHash>friends;
    people(int x) : id(x) {}
};
```

But the compiler said:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const people' and 'const people')
        {return __x == __y;}
```

I have no idea how to deal with this...Any help?

Comment: Implement `people::operator==`. If two instances have the same hash value, they will them be compared for equality.

Comment: You have more than just a hashing issue. The class in the unordered container must also implement the `==` operator, and  the class in the container must be a complete type, which can't happen until the definition of `people` is complete. This is more than just a circular dependency problem which, by itself, is trivially addressed with forward declarations.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for replying! I added the operator==, but it says error: overloaded 'operator==' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)...I don't understand...
        bool operator == (const people& x, const people& y){
            return x.id == y.id;
        }

Comment: Remove the second parameter `const people& y` and compare `x.id` against `this->id`. Or move the operator outside of the `struct people {...};` definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. `people` will be an incomplete type when you instantiate `std::unordered_set` which is undefined behavior. See http://eel.is/c++draft/library#res.on.functions.

Comment: Ummm.. But I need a type which describes the person's id and his friends, and I need to check if he and his friends have some common friends. If I use vector instead of set, every time I have to traverse the whole vector to find out the intersection, which would be very time consuming... Are there any better solution about this?